# Does Newton's generalized binomial theorem work on a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, binomial-theorem

My question is that does  Newton's generalized binomial theorem work on a matrix? In other words, for a Hermitian matrix $X$ and a real number $r$, is the following statement correct? Is there any condition on $X$ that makes the series valid/invalid?
$$(I+X)^r=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k} X^k$$

Comment: Banach-space structure on Hermitian matrices allows you to translate the proof for complex case *mutatis mutandis* to the proof for matrix case provided $\|X\| < 1$.

Comment: @SangchulLee it's not clear how one should define the $r$th power of an arbitrary Hermitian matrix.  For example, what exactly should $(-I)^{1/2}$ be? edit: never mind, that case doesn't arise with your constraint.

Comment: @Azoodish it is certainly possible to do so if $X$ is Hermitian with eigenvalues at least $-1$.  In any other case, one needs to be careful about what precisely the $r$th power of a matrix means.

Comment: This will indeed work when $\|X\| < 1$ ($\|\cdot\|$ meaning the spectral norm).  In any other case, there is no guarantee.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I agree that the statement does depend on how the $r$-th power is defined. As you may know, however, for $(1+X)^r$  with $\|X\|<1$, many definitions (definition using spectral theorem, definition using matrix logarithm and matrix exponential, taking the series in question as definition) coincide, though proving the equivalence is another story.

Comment: @SangchulLee also, *"mutatis mutandis"* is a nice turn of phrase, I'll be hanging on to that one

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I found that expression in a textbook (complex-analysis textbook if I remember correctly) and thought that it was really cool, but I was unsure how it reads like for native speakers... until now. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So it is correct if $||X||<1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Can you introduce a reference for this? I have difficulty in translating the proof  for complex case  to the proof for matrix case. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binomial theorem for matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913895/binomial-theorem-for-matrices)

Comment: @SangchulLee, well, the only speakers for whom mutatis mutandis was native have long been dead...

Comment: I suggest you decide on a specific dofinition of of what $X^r$ means, and then maybe someoner can offer a proof of what you want.