# Generalized binomial theorem for non-commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, binomial-theorem

I know that generalized binomial theorem for matrices, i.e. expansion of 
$$(A+B)^r\quad\quad (*)$$ when $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite matrices and $r$ is a real number, works only when $A$ and $B$ commute. For example, since the identity matrix commutes with all matrices, we have the expansion in this post:  [Does Newton's generalized binomial theorem work on a matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966878/does-newtons-generalized-binomial-theorem-work-on-a-matrix).

My question is that when $A$ and $B$ do not commute, is this possible to expand (*)  in the special case that $r$ is very close to 1, i.e. $r=1+\delta$ and $\delta$ is a real number which is very close to zero?

Comment: If one of your matrices is invertible, you can convert to $A(1+A^{-1}B)^r$ and apply the binomial theorem to this.

Comment: Both are invertible, but it is not possible because they don't commute and $r\neq 1$.

Comment: What is not possible? The identity $A+B = A(1+A^{-1}B)$ holds whenever $A$ is invertible. It's an application of the distributive law. In particular it holds when $A$ and $B$ do not commute.

Comment: $(A+B)^r\neq A^r(1+A^{-1}B)^r$ if $A$ and $B$ don't commute and $r\neq 1$.

Comment: You are right. I've made a horrible mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Well, purely formally, at least in physics, one routinely blunders into:
$$
(A+B)^{1+\delta}=(A+B) e^{\delta \ln (A+B)}=(A+B) \left (I+\delta \ln (A+B) + \frac{\delta^2}{2} (\ln (A+B))^2+...\right ) ,
$$
until the alarm bells start ringing.

But, beyond this,  you might need to know something about the norm of ln(*A+B*) to go any further, or else that of (*A+B*-I), so as to expand the log, formally,
$$
\ln (A+B)= \ln (I +(A+B-I))= A+B-I-\frac{1}{2}(A+B-I)^2+...
$$
using $\ln (1+x)= x-x^2/2+...$ for "small" *x*, 
cf. [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix), or the eigenvalues of the sum, etc... Smallness of the matrix *A+B-I* corresponds to a small norm, as utilized in physics and engineering.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have a proof for your answer? It is not very obvious to me why it is correct.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. This is interesting and  should be useful in some applications, but I need an expansion that separates  $A$ and $B$. i.e. it is in terms of powers of $A$ and $B$ not $A+B$ ... which might not exist when $A$ and $B$ don't commute.

Comment: There is nothing general around... That was part of the point: practical progress is predicated on the specific properties of *A* and *B* or *A+B-I* from that point on...